# Iphone/Android - general approach for connect from application to db

Tags: android, iphone, xcode

I have problem with application for Iphone/Android.
I would connect to db server in application but I don't know about how?
I use xml-rpc or soap, it is good but sometime data exchange is very slowly.
What are is other metotd for connect to get data from db server, for mobile application?

I mean the general approach for connect from application to db (data exchange).

Thank you for help.

Comment: I try search good solution for exchange data in iphone/android to db

Comment: I don't understand completely what's the problem. Do you mean a long data-loading time by a slow data exchange ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very abstract in nature , please try to be precise from next , I hope this will help you. I am assuming that you have web-services for interaction with DB server . 
Now depending on the type of web-service , there are various library for sending and receiving data like KSOAP2 in android for SOAP based . Try to google u will find lot of example ..